# Getting calculated value from one function inside another function

Tags: php, class, function, this, return-value

I have faced a little problem I can't seem to figure out. 
I have a calculation class that calculates som quantities from various values and the I need those calculated values inside another function that will output a list with quantities, prices etc.

But I can't get the values. I just get:

```
Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in
```

The function that prints the list is inside a class called Matliste

```
function PrintList($rid, $fields_to_select = array()) {
        $matliste = new Matliste;
        $matliste->GetCalculation($_GET["house"]);

        $types = join(",", $fields_to_select);

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM nt_stentyper INNER JOIN nt_tunliste ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer INNER JOIN nt_priser ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_priser.varenummer WHERE nt_stentyper.tagsten = $rid AND nt_stentyper.prod_type IN ($types) ORDER BY nt_stentyper.prod_type ASC";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        $markers = array();

        $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] = "";

        $prodTypes = array("1" => $this->roofTiles, "2" => $this->roofBinders);

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= '<tr>';
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>". $row["varenummer"] ."</td>";
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>". $row["tunnummer"] ."</td>";
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>". $row["beskrivelse"] ."</td>";
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>". $prodTypes[$row["prod_type"]] ."</td>";
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>stk</td>";
            $markers["###TABLEROWS###"] .= "<td>". str_replace(".", ",", $row["pris_dk"]) ." kr.</td>";
        } 

        $finalPrice = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT *, SUM(pris_dk) AS pris FROM nt_stentyper INNER JOIN nt_tunliste ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_tunliste.varenummer INNER JOIN nt_priser ON nt_stentyper.varenr_tilb = nt_priser.varenummer WHERE nt_stentyper.tagsten = $rid AND nt_stentyper.prod_type IN ($types)"));
        $markers["###FINALPRICE###"] =  str_replace(".", ",", $finalPrice["pris"]);
        $markers["###LIST_FOR###"] = ($finalPrice["prod_type"] == 1) ? $finalPrice["beskrivelse"] : "";
        $markers["###PERCENTAGE###"] = $_GET["spild"];
        Main::GetMarkers($markers);
    }
```

$this->roofTiles and $this->roofBinders gives me the fatal error mentioned above.

$this->roofTiles is calculated in the function in the Calculation class and is like this:

```
$this->Rooftiles = ceil((($areal_tagflade*$forbrug-$antaldblvinge*$daekbredde_dv_venstre_2-$antal_topsten-2))*$perc / 2) * 2;
```

but in the PrintList function I cannot get that value.

$matliste->GetCalculation is this:

```
function GetCalculation($house) {          

        $calculations = new HouseCalculations;

        switch($house) {
            case 1:
                $calculations->calc_normal($_GET["rid"], $_GET["rooftiletype"], $_GET["afslutning_sten"], (isset($_GET["wa"])) ? $_GET["wa"] : 0, (isset($_GET["kviste_1"])), (isset($_GET["kviste_2"])));                      
              break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `HouseCalculations` shouldn't be `HouseCalculations()`? Just asking, you might accidentally initialize the constructor of the constructor itself (or something).

Comment: Are you sure that in the first function you want to call `$this->roofTiles` and not `$matliste->roofTiles`? Seems strange that the method inits an object like the parent one, executes another method and then queries the property of itself and not of an inited object.

Comment: @ashein - Can you give me an example? Not 100% sure what you mean.

Comment: @Morten Hagh `$matliste->GetCalculation($_GET["house"]);` goes before `$prodTypes = array("1" => $this->roofTiles, "2" => $this->roofBinders);`, but there should be `$prodTypes = array("1" => $matliste->roofTiles, "2" => $matliste->roofBinders);`, i suppose. As i can gather it, you init your `$matliste` and run a method that calculates the `roofTiles` variable that is stored in that very object, and then trying to read the property of another object.
Anyway that wouldn't be the reason of your error, it seems by the look of it that the method is defined outside of the class scope.

Comment: Is calc_normal storing its results in the HouseCalculation object? If so, getCalculation should return the calculation object, which you can then store in a variable in the PrintList method and read the properties of that to get your answers.

Comment: @Braiba - I can easily get the results in getCalculation. If I do a var_dump($calculations->roofTiles) I get the calculated value. So I might be on the right track here. How can I store it in PrintList?

Comment: @ashein - $matliste->roofTiles outputs NULL but I think I am narrowing it down.

Comment: Wait a minute - I think @ashein got something. Would it do any harm to move the switch statement down to the PrintList function? Then I got the result right away? Seems quite overkill to have a method that does no more than getting a calculation.